Let $I=(x^2+x+1)$. Is $\Bbb Z_3[x]/I$ an integral domain?
Let $I=(x^2+x+1)$. Is $\Bbb Z_3[x]/I$ an integral domain?
My solution goes like this:
If $\Bbb Z_3[x]/I$ is an integral domain then $I$ is a prime ideal. But $I$ is a non-zero prime ideal and since, ($\Bbb Z_3$ is a field so, $\Bbb Z_3[x]$ is a Euclidean domain due to which,) $\Bbb Z_3[x]$ is a PID,  $I$ is a maximal ideal in $Z_3[x]$ since every non-zero prime ideal in a PID is a maximal ideal.
Now, we know that an ideal $(p)$ (,where $p\in R$) in a Euclidean domain $R$ is a maximal ideal iff $p$ is irreducible in $R.$ Using this theorem, we can say that $x^2+x+1$ is irreducible in $\Bbb Z_3[x].$ But, $x^2+x+1$ is reducible in $\Bbb Z_3[x]$ since $1$ is root of $x^2+x+1.$ This is a contradiction. So, $\Bbb Z_3[x]/I$ is not an integral domain.

Is there anything that needs to changed to improve the clarity of the proof? Can the presentation of this proof be improved to improve the readability of the solution? Finally, if there's anything wrong with my proof, please feel free to point it out.

You can streamline this a bit using your observation at the end. There are two nonzero elements in the quotient that multiply to $0$ because the polynomial can be factored. You don't need the discussion at the top at all, though it doesn't hurt to have that in mind.

I don't think you need the proof by contradiction.  Wouldn't you just want to directly show that $p$ is reducible?

Simply say that in this quotient, the square of the nonzero (class mod $I$ of) $x-1$ is zero.

For a solution-verification question to be on topic you must specify precisely which step in the proof you question, and why so. This site is not meant to be used as a proof checking machine.

@BillDubuque Wait, but I removed the tag a long time ago. Maybe, you posted the comment earlier than that, but I was notified recently about it.

Removing the tag doesn't change the fact that the question is an SV. $\ \ $

@BillDubuque Actually, I know my solution's valid.  I am seeking suggestions on how to make the proof better by using more explanations so that the readability gets enhanced.

That contradicts what you wrote "if there's anything wrong with my proof...".  In any case the site is not meant for questions like this. It is a Q&A site, not a site meant for teaching how to polish or check proofs.

@BillDubuque Ah, I wrote that line, "if there's anything wrong with my proof..." just in case any errors have crept in it that might have been overlooked by me. I just wrote that as a part of a necessary precaution, so that my proof doesn't end up misleading someone. My primary aim was to improve the content readability as I mentioned previously. If you suggest I will surely remove that line, for now I know that there are no such overlooked errors. I wish to adhere by the site's guidelines. Moreover, you may edit my post to make it more appropriate for the site. Thank you!
